# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u with Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am stumped as to how to solve/diagnose ajax/jquery error.

This is my function:

```
   var LogIn = {
        Email: $("#Name").val(),
        MobileNo: $("#txtMobileNumber").val(),
        PinCode: '',
        Message: '',
        Success:false
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
         contentType: "application/json",
        url: "https://a different server domain/api/LoginRequest",
        data: JSON.stringify(LogIn),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divError").html(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
            $("#divError").html(jsonValue);
        }
    });
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: It might be `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support using POST and jsonp and the reason for that is very simple: when you inject a `<script>` tag into the DOM (which is what jQuery does when you use jsonp), the browser will send a GET request to the remote endpoint which has been referred to in the `src` property of this tag.

So basically you will need to use GET instead:

```
type: "GET"
```

Also since the data is sent as query string parameters you should remove the content type:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

and do not `JSON.stringify` the data.

And here's the full example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://a different server domain/api/LoginRequest",
    data: LogIn,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divError").html(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
        $("#divError").html(jsonValue);
    }
});
```

Of course this will work only if the remote endpoint supports JSONP and the GET verb.

Personally I would recommend using CORS instead of JSONP as it would give you much more options. You will be able to use POST in this case. Please refer to the following material as it seems you are using ASP.NET Web API on the server and trying to make a cross domain AJAX call: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: thanks for speedy reply.  I am using FromBody on REST API side. Will that make a difference?  Will try now your suggestion - thanks  NB:        [HttpGet]
        [Route("LoginRequest")]
        public string LoginRequest([FromBody]Login login)

Comment: You should remove `[FromBody]` because when you make a GET request, the body is empty. IIRC you should use `[FromUri]` instead. Also make sure that you return JSONP content instead of JSON from your API or the request will fail.

Comment: ~I have no idea if my asp.net app supports jsop or not. It is something I used from a previous SO question and answer. Suppose it does not,  should I revert back to json?

Comment: Yes, if you don't know if your API supports JSONP, then it would be better to use CORS instead. I would recommend you reading this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api